# The differences between DurationConstraint and DurationInterval

Tags: uml

A `DurationConstraint` is a Constraint that refers to a DurationInterval.

A `DurationInterval` defines the range between two Durations.

Is there an example clarify the difference?

PS:the above definition are from UML specification

Answer (score 1):

A DurationInterval is an Interval of Duration i.e. you define range with a minimal Duration and a maximal Duration. This will help you to model things like an given execution takes **between 2 seconds and 3 hours** to execute.

A DurationConstraint is a constraint referencing a DurationInterval i.e. you model a constraint on a duration which will be evaluated according to the minimal duration and the maximum duration defined in the DurationInterval. For example this will help you to define the following constraint  **this execution takes between 2 seconds and 3 hours** where **between 2 seconds and 3 hours** is the referenced DurationInterval.

Hoping it helps.

RB

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to say about `DurationInterval` . you can take a look at the following simple diagram:
http://postimg.org/image/n855215qb/

I have defined the range using constraint element  with a `minimal Duration (2seconds)` and a `maximal Duration(3hours)` 
but don't know how the `DurationConstraint` looks like?
PS:I am using Modelio for modeling the above Diagram

Comment: You are righ, but want do you mean by "look like" ? you mean graphically or the content?

Comment: Hi@Red Beard ! I mean How the `DurationConstraint`can be modelled in Modelio(graphically + content)?